# Raman or FTIR spectroscopy to identify metals?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, raman

Metals are opaque, so doesn't most of the light reflect? And does the IR source even cause vibrations in the metal?
Same goes for Raman spectroscopy, is it useful for use of metal identification?

Is it better to use EDS to identify unknown metals?

Comment: Well, you obviously cannot measure in absorption, unless you have a very thin film. ATR will of course work. Spoiler: The spectra will look terribly boring, and you won´t be able to differentiate much.

Comment: I guess it is better to use XRD to identify metals, instead of raman or FTIR.